# Compilation issue with enum in Scala using type with value

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, I have the following code. I am trying to run it in Eclipse. It shows compilation issue.

```
object TestEnum2 extends Enumeration {

  type Donut = Value
  val Glazed      = Value("Glazed")
  val Strawberry  = Value("Strawberry")
  val Plain       = Value("Plain")
  val Vanilla     = Value("Vanilla")

  def show() {
    println(s"Vanilla Donut string value = ${Donut.Vanilla}");
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    show();
  }
}
```

It shows the following error as given in the image. It gives error

> Not Found: value Donut

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Donut` is the name of type. The values are called `TestEnum2.Vanilla` or in your case, since it is already in scope, just `Vanilla`.

```
println(s"Vanilla Donut string value = ${Vanilla}");
```

As an aside, enumerations in Scala 2.x are a bit rough. I recommend either taking a look at [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) or using Java enums.

Comment: Sir, I got the answer, by the way how do I print the all values of Donut type, I mean can I write like this ${Donut.values} ? When I write it gives me again compilation issue.

Comment: `${TestEnum2.values}`

Comment: Sir, I think what I am referring the docs for Scala in internet is bit messy for enumerations particularly in 2.12.3 version.